# How to prevent Google Chrome from suspending unused tabs

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

After the last update/build my Chromebook got (57.0.29) it suspends unused tabs to "Save system resources" this has been annoying me for a while I tried going to `chrome://flags` but I found nothing there and checked the settings but there was nothing related.

My question is: how to disable chrome from suspending unused tabs? I have crouton installed and I am in dev mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same setup, and I am unable to reproduce this.
Are you sure that some extension is not doing this?
Are you able to restore the last closed tab using `ctrl+shift+t`?

Edit:
I found chrome://flags #memory-pressure-thresholds

It is called: "Memory discard strategy for advanced pressure handling"
Options are:

- default
- conservative memory pressure release strategy
- aggressive cache release strategy
- aggressive tab discard release strategy
- aggressive cache and tab release strategy

Comment: it is suspended not closed wich means I have to reload not reopen